# Translating object oriented programs to their procedural equivalents

Tags: object-oriented

I'm new to the field of program transformation.  I'm looking for resources on the techniques and methods one would use to translate object oriented code to its procedural equivalent.  In particular, I need to translate arbitrary PHP programs written with Object Oriented constructs into purely procedural PHP programs.

I know there are many source transformation tools out there that can assist in this like txl, antlr, ROSE, etc.  What I'm looking for is some direction into how to deconstruct the Object Oriented features into their procedural equivalents so that I can begin to develop the set of rules that these transformation programs require.

Maybe my google-fu is not up to snuff but I am having trouble finding links to papers or websites that detail converting OO code into procedural code.

Thanks for pointers to any resources.